# data frame check if the condition is matching with correspond value

Tags: python, dataframe

Let's say I have a data frame like:

```
    print(df)

    category size
    large 100
    small 10
    medium 50
    small 10
    medium 40
    large 120
```

I want to check between category and size whether the size has the exact value corresponding to the category.

```
large == 100, medium == 50 and small == 10.
```

I want to use given below syntax:

```
for df_index, df_line in df.iterrows():
```

And if a line has mismatching, then leave that line, otherwise, drop a well-matched line.
The output should be like:
        print(df)

```
    category size
    medium 40
    large 120
```

Comment: What is the desired output ?

Comment: @AlexandreB. added the desired ouput

Comment: It is still unclear what an output you want to have. Just list the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one based on your question; it's basic but easy to understand:

```
import pandas as pd

size_chart = {'large':100, 'medium': 50, 'small': 10}
data = {'category': ['large', 'small', 'medium', 'small', 'medium', 'medium'], 'size': [100, 10, 50, 10, 50, 100] } 
df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['category','size'])
rows_list = []
for df_index, df_line in df.iterrows():
    if df_line['size'] != size_chart[df_line['category']]: rows_list.append( {'category':df_line['category'],'size':df_line['size']} )
df2 = pd.DataFrame (rows_list, columns = ['category','size'])
print (df2)
```

Prints:

```
  category  size
0   medium   100
```

Comment: Very helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

Even if you asked a solution using `iterrows`, I will give you a way not using it. The `iterrows` method is very easy to use, but leads to non scalable code because it is an expensive operation in pandas. As much as possible, you should try to use *vectorized* methods which use C optimized code. Here you could:

1. build a reference dataframe

   ```
   ref = pd.DataFrame([['large', 100], ['medium', 50], ['small', 10]],
              columns=df.columns)
   ```
2. merge it into the original dataframe and keep rows with mismatching values:

   ```
   df.merge(ref, how='left', on='category', suffixes=('', '_ref')).query(
       "size != size_ref")[['category', 'size']]
   ```

It gives as expected:

```
  category  size
4   medium    40
5    large   120
```

Comment: Thanks for the other perspective. As you said, iterrows takes more computational power but I need this method for the other purpose. I'm considering to use dictionary, e.g. size_dict = {small: 10, medium: 50, large: 100}. Can I use this method to stick to the iterrows method?